# Set Location on Android emulator

Tags: android, emulation

How to set a specific location on Android emulator ? Set Location Button is disabled. Before we could set Lat Long. now it is not possible .
[image: This is an emulator . Set Location button is disabled]

Answer (score 3):

Once the map finish loading, you can select any point in the map and then the SET LOCATION button will be enabled. No need to enter the lat and long manually anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try emulator console - [developer.android-emulator-console](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-console)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try re-creating the emulator and also make sure you have the latest Google Play services installed (Emulator menu > Google Play > Update).

I've tried the same api level with the same device (Nexus 5X) and the google map open's up for me normally.[image]